# Warning in gzfile(file, "rb")

Tags: r, shiny, shinyapps

My application is running perfectly fine in local machine but when uploaded to [shinyapps.io](https://shinyapps.io) its throwing the following error.

```
Warning in gzfile(file, "rb") :  cannot open compressed file 'model2.RDS', probable reason 'No such file or directory'.
```

`model2.RDS` file exist in the same directory where `ui.R` and `shiny.R` exist.

Source Code:

```
library(shiny)
library(ANLP)

modelelem <- readRDS("model2.RDS")

shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  observe({
    text1 <- reactive({input$text})
    Predicted1 <- NULL
    Predicted1 <- predict_Backoff(text1(), modelelem, isDebugMode = F)
    output$Predicted <- renderText({Predicted1})
  })
})
```